# What are these double arrows on a schematic?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, kicad

If I have to reproduce this schematic in KiCad, what should I use?

[image]

How do I represent Vin+ in KiCad? Is this a local or global label?

[image]

Comment: Looks like Orcad's version of off-page connectors, specifically.

Comment: Altium's, or an earlier version such as PCAD, actually -- the ground symbols are distinctive. Specifically, these objects are called "Off-Sheet Connectors"; they name the net.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *What are these double arrows on a schematic?*

It looks to me like what is called an off-page connector but, it may be called something else in the drawing package originally used. You can use a global label in KiCAD (CTR_L): -

[image]

> *Also how do I represent Vin+ in Kicad? Is this a label (local or
> global)?*

The example I drew above allows you to name the global label however you want i.e. any nets connected to it will assume that name. I chose to name it "hello".

Comment: thank you. Last question, if you allow me, how do I make the difference between local and global label? If the label is used in multiple sheets can I considere it as a global label or it is more complicate than that?

Comment: @ClassyFied if you are not using a hierarchical design you would just use global labels. If you are using a hierarchical design then use the appropriate hierarchical label type. A label used on multiple sheets would be regarded as a global label. For me, I never use hierarchical designs and I always use labels that act globally.

Comment: thank you and lastly, based on the picture I shown in the first post, how do I know the type the hierachical label (input, output, birdirectional, tri-state, passive) ?

Comment: I can't give you that answer other than direct you to uncover what the original schematic was drawn in and look in the user documentation of that software. I will add this though; if you are wanting to redraw it in KiCAD but not use it for circuit simulation, then it won't matter.